# How to create EF Core migrations while using Clean Architecture, if it needs to use startup project?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design, .net-7.0, clean-architecture

I have class libraries `Core`, `Application`, `Infrastructure`, and one `Web` project which is ASP NET 7 project.

The `Infrastructure` layer is data access layer, so I have defined `DbContext` here and also wanted to have migrations here. So I used below command:

```
add-migration UsersMig -Context UsersDbContext -o Migrations/Users
```

But this command shouts that:

> Your startup project 'Web' doesn't reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design. This package is required for the Entity Framework Core Tools to work. Ensure your startup project is correct, install the package, and try again.

But I don't want to reference something that is related to data access in my `Web` layer. So I setted up my class library as startup project (yes, pretty bad idea, classlib is not executable...) like this:

```
dotnet ef migrations add UsersMig --context UsersDbContext --project src/BFF/BFF.Infrastructure/BFF.Infrastructure.csproj --startup-project src/BFF/BFF.Infrastructure/BFF.Infrastructure.csproj
```

And I got error:

> Unable to create an object of type 'UsersDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

So what I need to do to have migrations in my `Infrastructure` layer without biting Clean Architecture?

Answer (score 2):

You're right in wanting to keep your Web layer decoupled from the data access concerns. The error you're seeing is because the EF Core tools need certain design-time services that are provided by the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` package. However, you don't necessarily need to add this package to your Web layer. Instead, you can add it to your Infrastructure layer where your DbContext is defined.

Try my suggestions below to set up migrations in your Infrastructure layer without violating the Clean Architecture principles:

1. **Add Necessary Packages**:
   Ensure that your Infrastructure project has the following NuGet packages:

   - `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`
   - `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design`
   - `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` (or whatever database provider you're using)
2. **DbContext Configuration**:
   Ensure that your `UsersDbContext` has a constructor that accepts `DbContextOptions<UsersDbContext>` as a parameter. This is necessary for EF Core tools to be able to create an instance of your context at design time.

   ```cs
   public UsersDbContext(DbContextOptions<UsersDbContext> options) : base(options)
   {
   }
   ```
3. **Design-Time DbContext Factory**:
   Create a design-time `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<TContext>` implementation in your Infrastructure layer. This factory helps EF Core tools instantiate your DbContext.

   ```cs
   using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
   using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;

   public class UsersDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<UsersDbContext>
   {
       public UsersDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
       {
           var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<UsersDbContext>();
           optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Your_Connection_String_Here");

           return new UsersDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
       }
   }
   ```

   Note: Replace `"Your_Connection_String_Here"` with your actual connection string. This is only for design-time, so it's okay to hard-code it here, but ensure you don't accidentally commit sensitive data to source control.
4. **Run Migrations Command**:
   Now, you should be able to run the migrations command without specifying the `--startup-project`:

   ```bash
   dotnet ef migrations add UsersMig --context UsersDbContext --project src/BFF/BFF.Infrastructure/BFF.Infrastructure.csproj
   ```
5. **Update Database**:
   When you're ready to apply the migrations to the database, you can use the `database update` command:

   ```bash
   dotnet ef database update --context UsersDbContext --project src/BFF/BFF.Infrastructure/BFF.Infrastructure.csproj
   ```

By following these steps, you can keep your Web layer decoupled from data access concerns and still leverage EF Core migrations in your Infrastructure layer.

Comment: I can create migrations but updating database throws due to connection fail. I checked my connection string twice, it's valid.